# Python struct appears inaccurate

Tags: python, struct

I have four bytes from a raw socket: value=0xc0ff00c0. Using struct with a format of L (or I for that matter) to unpack

```
struct.unpack("=L",value)
```

I get 3221290944. Using

```
int(hexlify(value),16)
```

I get 3237937344. The latter is correct. I have not noticed this with other format specifiers so I assume it must have something to do with the larger integral structures like Long. Has anyone else noticed this? Thanks

Comment: Is the value packed with python?

Comment: Also using `struct.unpack("!L",value)` or `struct.unpack(">L",value)`. Yields the correct result. `!` means network format. So I'm guessing that is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should unpack with:

```
struct.unpack("!L",value)
```

Since data is sent over network you should unpack using network ordering - `!`

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)